# Applescript administrator privledges but *not* running a shell script

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm trying to get my Applescript code to have administrator privileges. However, the only solution I find by googling is:

```
do shell script "command" user name "me" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges
```

I'm not running a shell command.. I'm using pure Applescript. My code I'm doing is:

```
on run {input, parameters} -- copy
    repeat with aFile in input
        tell application "Finder"
            if name extension of aFile is "component" then
                copy aFile to "/Library/Audio/Plug-ins/Components" 
            else if name extension of aFile is "vst" then
                copy aFile to "/Library/Audio/Plug-ins/VST"
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end run
```

Is there anyway to get admin privileges while using pure Applescript?

Answer (score 0):

Your handler starts with `on run {input, parameters}` so I think we are talking about a **execute applescript** step inside an Automator workflow. At this point I think the Automator action is always executed inside the current user's context.

**BUT:** Of course you can use the `do shell script` inside the executed Applescript action and at that moment you can give the administrator privileges to that do shell call. I've rebuilt your handler in the following way:

```
on run {input, parameters} -- copy
    -- collect all resulting cp statements in a list for later use
    set cpCalls to {}

    -- walk through the files
    repeat with aFile in input
        tell application "System Events"
            -- get the file extension
            set fileExt to name extension of aFile
            -- get the posix path of the file
            set posixFilePath to POSIX path of aFile
        end tell
        if fileExt is "component" then
            -- adding the components cp statement to the end of the list
            set end of cpCalls to "cp " & quoted form of posixFilePath & " /Library/Audio/Plug-ins/Components/"
        else if fileExt is "vst" then
            -- adding the vat cp statement to the end of the list
            set end of cpCalls to "cp " & quoted form of posixFilePath & " /Library/Audio/Plug-ins/VST/"
        end if
    end repeat

    -- check if there were files to copy
    if cpCalls ≠ {} then
        -- combine all cp statements with "; " between
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "; "
        set allCpCallsInOne to cpCalls as text
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

        -- execute all cp statements in one shell script call
        do shell script allCpCallsInOne with administrator privileges
    end if  
end run
```

The action now asks for the administrator credentials but you can add `user name "me" password "my password"` if you like.

To avoid prompting for credentials for each `cp` I collect all calls in a list and execute them at once at the end of the handler.

Greetings, Michael / Hamburg